# Turn off code contracts warning

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compiler-warnings, code-contracts

I want to turn off a code contract warning, but only for specific code lines. How do I do that?

For instance, I get:

```
Warning 87  CodeContracts: requires unproven: key != null
```

for:

```
return HttpContext.Current.Items[typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName];
```

which will never happen in our applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, one option would be:

```
string key = typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName;
Contract.Assume(key != null);
return HttpContext.Current.Items[key];
```

It's a bit ugly, but I believe it should work.